# Error analysis of Estrin's method

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, na.numerical-analysis

[Estrin's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme) is an alternative to [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for evaluating polynomials. To evaluate a polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^7 a_i x^i$ at a point $x\in\mathbb R$, it first computes the powers $x^2$ and $x^4$ and then uses the decomposition:

$$P(x) = (a_0 + a_1 x) + (a_2 + a_3x) x^2 + ((a_4 + a_5 x) + (a_6 + a_7 x) x^2)x^4.$$

This turns out to be faster than Horner's method on modern computers, since the four $a_i + a_{i+1}x$ terms can be computed in parallel.

Books like "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, Second Edition" study the numerical accuracy of Horner's method.
See also [this discussion](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/13023) on the other Computer Science stackexchange, or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436643/horners-method) on math stackexchange.

However, I've been unable to find any papers covering Estrin's method.
Is anyone aware whether Estrin's method is as stable as Horner's method? Or how much worse?

Comment: If anything, I’d expect it to be better rather than worse. But I’m no expert in these matters.

Comment: From experiments here it sadly seems worse: https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/932 I'd be interested in ideas for making it more accurate.